# Работа с SMS в Android

Tags: android, sms

Собственно интересует как работать с SMS в Android.

Конкретно :

1. Отправка сообщения. При отправке сообщения programmatically записывается ли оно в базу?
2. Как удалить SMS из таблицы?
3. Как редактировать SMS в базе?

P.S. О манифесте, пермишеннах не стоит говорить. Конкретно интересуют вопросы выше.

Answer (score 7):

1) Программная отправка сообщения (не через `Intent`) - это просто. Гуглится легко - даже не буду давать ссылку. При отправке в базу не пишется - надо самому заниматься примерно так:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", "123456789");
values.put("body", "foo bar");
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

2) Удаление SMS из базы также достаточно просто:

```
 activity.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null); //id - идентификатор сообщения
```

3) Редактирование идентично. Надо получить список SMS, далее по id вытащить нужную, потом записать обратно.

В манифесте надо держать пару пермишенов:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Наиболее сложная часть это перехват входящих сообщений - там много недокументированных фич. Только в KitKat появилась официальная поддержка перехвата входящих сообщений.

Comment: Не совсем понятно откуда вы взяли поля address и body. Какие еще поля можно заполнять? + откуда берется id сообщения? Прикрепите пожалуйста snippet по чтению СМС из базы.

Answer (score -6):

Работать с SMS в андроиде нельзя, кажется в API 19 что-то появилось но врятли.
Можно через хак читать смс, но не факт что это будет работать на всех устройствах.

Comment: А что касается http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html ??

Comment: Этот API позволяет отправлять SMS.

Comment: @psyhitus вы не правы, причем глубоко не правы...